# use statement not working for Yii2 vendor

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm installed this [plugin](https://github.com/filsh/yii2-flags) using composer.

`Flags.php` class is in the `vendor/filsh/yii2-flags/yii/flags/` directory

When i add this in my view

```
use filsh\yii2flags\yii\flags\Flags;

echo Flags::widget([
    'flag' => 'UA',
    'type' => Flags::FLAT_24,
    'useSprite' => false // use sprite image? default is false
]);
```

i'm getting a `Class 'filsh\yii2flags\yii\flags\Flags' not found` error.

i also tried `use vendor\filsh\yii2flags\yii\flags\Flags;` but still no luck.

What am i doing wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: try `use yii\flags\Flags`

Comment: @InsaneSkull thank you. can help explain why? isn't use supposed to be the dir of the class?

Comment: It's mapped in the composer of plugin that how namespace will be created [See here](https://github.com/filsh/yii2-flags/blob/master/composer.json)

Comment: The namespace of class is defined in file where the class is defined. [See source](https://github.com/filsh/yii2-flags/blob/fe0c0ab73c4a0ccb3e49d4b59a93a8549cfed42d/Flags.php#L3)
The setting in composer.json only serve to set up mapping namespace to folder for autoload generated by composer.

Answer (score 0):

```
use yii\flags\Flags;

use yii\flags\FlagsAsset;


FlagsAsset::register($this);


<?= Flags::widget([

  'flag' => 'UA',

  'type' => Flags::FLAT_24,

  'useSprite' => false // use sprite image? default is false

]); ?>
```

Try this hope this will be useful